# Get only users who belong to a specific group

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to understand Active Directory as quickly as I can, but so far I haven't been very successful. I have this code that returns all the users from AD which somebody else wrote and I'm supposed to alter it so that it only returns the users for a specified group. I've tried to learn a little bit more about AD in the hopes that the solution will present itself, but no luck so far. So maybe someone can help me out? Here's the code that I have.

```
adSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))";
string groupName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADGroupName"];
string domain = adSearch.SearchRoot.Properties["dc"].Value.ToString();
DomainLabel.Text = domain + " accounts:";
foreach (SearchResult sResultSet in adSearch.FindAll())
{
    if (!GetProperty(sResultSet, "givenName").Equals("") && !GetProperty(sResultSet, "sn").Equals(""))
    {
        string userAccountControl = GetProperty(sResultSet, "useraccountcontrol");
        bool x = userAccountControl.Equals("512") || userAccountControl.Equals("66048");
        if (x)
        {

           ListItem tempItem = new ListItem();
           unsortedList.Add(GetProperty(sResultSet, "givenName") + " " + GetProperty(sResultSet, "sn"));
           tempItem.Text = GetProperty(sResultSet, "givenName") + " " + GetProperty(sResultSet, "sn");
           tempItem.Value = GetProperty(sResultSet, "sAMAccountName");
           values.Add(tempItem);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the most trivial problem to solve. Do you just need direct members of the group, or do you need the effective membership (recursive evaluation)?

Comment: I believe only direct members are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this in this way Where it checks the username if its in the SecurityGroup. You can Get the Users in the ActiveDirectory and then check it like this

```
public bool IsInSecurityGroup(string UserName)
    {
       bool _isInsecurityGroup;
                    string GroupName ="GroupName";
                    System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity MyIdentity = 
                    System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
                    System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal MyPrincipal = new 
                    System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(MyIdentity);

             return (MyPrincipal.IsInRole(GroupName)) ? true : false;


    }
```

For checking multiple users it should work for you [Getting Users From SecurityGroup](http://blogs.technet.com/b/brad_rutkowski/archive/2008/04/15/c-getting-members-of-a-group-the-easy-way-with-net-3-5-discussion-groups-nested-recursive-security-groups-etc.aspx)
 or this [GroupPrincipal.GetMembers Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339975.aspx)

Comment: Where is _isInsecurityGroup supposed to come from?

Comment: Sorry i was using as a property but now modified as a function so you can use it pass the username and it will return that its a part of security group or not.

Comment: Does this just get the current user's group? It doesn't seem to work for selecting all users from a group.

Comment: Also, it seems that UserName goes unused in the function.

Comment: i m using it for current windows user that is logged into our application that makes it valid for a user that's passed in this function.

Comment: I have edited the answer with a link that explains how to achieve it.

Comment: That link helped a lot. Thanks!